# Adding permissions on Google Sheet doesn't work despite 200 from API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using a service account with a project that has both GoogleDrive and Google Sheets API enabled. I am trying to add permissions to an already existing Google Sheet (created by the same service account). The API is returning like it succeeds but the permissions remained unchanged.

Client config:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
GOOGLE_CLIENT = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

using Google Drive V3 API:

```
new_permission = {
    'type': "user",
    'emailAddress': 'user@123.com',
    'role': "writer"
}

response = GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT.permissions().create(
    fileId=GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID, fields='*', body=new_permission).execute()
```

The response I get is:

```
{'kind': 'drive#permission', 'id': '1X2680991XXX793XX1308', 'type': 'user', 'emailAddress': 'user@123.com', 'role': 'writer', 'displayName': 'Jeff Bezos', 'deleted': False}
```

Then I run list permissions but it returns empty:

```
permissions = GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT.permissions().list(fileId=GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID).execute()
print(permissions.get('items', []))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the permission list with the service account using Drive API v3.
- You want to achieve this using google-api-python-client with python.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In your script, Drive API v3 is used. But from `permissions.get('items', [])`, it seems that you are trying to use Drive API v2. By this, the empty array is returned. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
permissions = GOOGLE_DRIVE_CLIENT.permissions().list(fileId=GOOGLE_SHEETS_ID).execute()
print(permissions.get('items', []))
```

#### To:

```
permissions = service.permissions().list(fileId=fileId, fields='*').execute()
print(permissions.get('permissions', []))
```

- In this modification, the permission list is retrieved with Drive API v3.

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.